# web page: semi-transparent elements -> PNG

Tags: png, extract, html, transparent

I have a web site that makes use of CSS box shadows. To make the web site look good in more browsers, I want to make use of semi-transparent PNGs instead. And to avoid having to redraw elements in a graphics program, I would like to know:

> Is there a way to extract
>   semi-transparent elements from a web
>   page and store them in
>   semi-transparent PNGs?

One solution that I could try if I hadn't borrowed my Mac to a friend: print to PDF from Safari. If I'm lucky, then the PDF has all the elements stacked in layers.

Comment: Won't Safari on Windows do the same?

Comment: PDF is deeply intertwined in OS X. Furthermore Safari on Windows doesn't have a PDF export function built in. The ouptut by printer drivers such as Foxit PDF creator doesn't look like the rendering on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [render DOM elements to canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) via SVG and XHTML embedded in `<foreignObject>`.